# Captions for More Fields groups, not just individual fields

Tags: captions, customization

I'm using More Fields to create some meta boxes on my custom post type. Is it possible to have a caption for each "group" of fields in the More Fields options? I would like to provide some basic information on the post edit screen.

I see you can enter a caption for each individual field but it would be handy to be able to give the group a caption also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this point in time I would just as soon not use the More Fields plugin at all, as there are native functions that can do everything you probably want with custom fields. There seems to be no good documentation afoot and the plugin site is obviously not being updated.

Alternatively, [try WPAlchemy](http://www.farinspace.com/wpalchemy-metabox/#usage). Quite easy to make discrete meta boxes with multiple form elements and whatever else you want to put into them, including blocks of text.